# heroku disable for http scripts to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a few api's that require http access (non https. They don't work!)

In my rails application how would i go about changing this to make it work?

Here is what i've done so far. In my production.rb is

```
  config.force_ssl = false
```

Is there anything else i can do?

Sam

***Edit***

Heres my ajax code, (part of it)

```
  type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: 'URL HERE',
    success: function(json) {
```

The url is a http, however heroku changes it to https.

Sam

Comment: force ssl is a helper essentially that set to true, will load the https equivilent of the url that the user has entered.  So a user types "http://yoursite.com/shopping" and rails will load "https://yoursite.com/shopping".  Since that's not what you're trying to do, more explanation is necessary.  What doesn't work?  What are the errors?  Are these your custom api's?

Comment: @trh Sorry, I have a url inside an ajax call, The api url needs to be http not https, Ideas?

Comment: Can you provide some code?  I think I'm still not understanding how its failing.  The ajax snippet perhaps

Comment: @trh I'll add it in now